# Request for member of non-class type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to save a C-string to a instance of my Password class and I keep getting the error message

> request for member 'assign' in 'Password::password', which is of non-class type 'char [80]'

Here is the portion of code pertaining to the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Password
{
    const static string too_short;
    const static string no_upper;
    const static string no_lower;
    const static string no_digit;
    const static string no_punct;

    string end_message;
    int score;
    char password[80];
    string passwrd;

    public:
        Password (char word[])
        {
            password.assign(word);
            c_stringCheck();
        }
```

I'm truly at a loss.

Comment: Use `std::string` and just `: password(word)`.

Comment: C strings don't have members.

Comment: Maybe you mean `passwrd.assign(word);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays of characters don't have methods, but you're trying to call `assign` on one. Perhaps use `strcpy`, `strncpy`, the non-standard `strlcpy`, or an idiomatic C++ equivalent instead.

Comment: ahhh thats right, im treating it as a string class instead of a C-string

Answer (score 0):

password is only a char array.
so you can't all password.assign() function.
try strcpy!